# How to call jQuery function using web browsers control C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I want to call a jQuery event from C# via web browser control.

Here's the jQuery function:

```
$("#veh-brand").change(function() {
    var brand = $(this).val();
    var dataString = "brand=" + brand;
    $text = $("#veh-brand [value='" + brand + "']").text();
    $('#full-car').html($text);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/external/ws-brand_year.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            var html = "<option value=''>Escoger</option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                html += "<option class='contrast' value=" + response[i].id + ">" + response[i].description + "</option>"
            }
            $("#veh-brand-year").html(html);
        }
    });
});

this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("change");
```

Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using invoke you can call just methods like this:

```
function change(){
}
```

Don't put in document ready trigger. Method must be located on accessible level.

Just write code which will call needed method in change() and call it.

If you use invokescript you should put inside JS code, not method name.

Comment: I am scrapping the site and I just want to call the change event of select tag. There are many select tags but I only want to call change method of select tag with ID "s" so I called my code like this webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript(@"$(""#s"")trigger(""change"");");

Comment: I am not the owner of the site all I can do is just calling the Jquery events so again the same question, how I can call Jquery change event of the dropdown.

Comment: Try to do this one, on web page:  function myFunction(){ $(""#s"").change(); } and in cs file webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript ("myFunction()");;

Comment: how I can add javascript code in someone's site because I am not the owner of the site. I am a public user and what I can do is just to call functions etc. so how I can call Jquery functions in C# using web browser

Comment: Sory for your waiting. You can add your js code to body of some html element by using webBrowser.Document.Body.GetElementByID("elemnt").OuterHtml. Try just add js script to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  dynamic tabclick = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { 
    "(function() {jQuery('.class').trigger('click');})()" });
```

I have used this in c# and it worked . we can write the jquery coding in that function.